# TYPO3 Extension: How should i aim for the slim controller?

Tags: typo3

As i'm a novice in TYPO3 extensions, i'm not sure what is the best way to do things. Whenever i create a specific record of a class it should get a Object Storage with objects of a lower class and this class should also get an Object Storage with objects of another lower class. All objects and Object Storages are the start conditions so to speak. Basically: Everytime a new record of a specific class is created, so far i had code in my createAction that created an object of another class and added it to the classes Object Storage. This in turn created objects of another class and added those to its own Object Storage. Everything was put in the createAction of the highest class.

But as this is the exact opposite of the principle of the slim controller. So I added the lines to each respective __construct of of each class, so that whenever the createAction of the highest class is performed, every object is still created with their objects in their Object Storages. I just put the logic in each constructor.

Is that the right way to do this?

Both ways work (putting everything in the createAction of the highest classe's controller OR splitting the logic to each classe's constructor). Is the second way really preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experiences say that the controller should be as slim as possible. I prefer to move all business logic which is possible to the model.

In your case I would do it in the model's constructor, too.